# How OpenCV C++ Interface Manage ROI

Tags: c++, opencv

Using OpenCV C++ interface how can I write code for setting and resetting ROI
For eg: If I need to code like

```
-> Load image
-> SetImageRoi
-> Do some processing on ROI region
-> Reset ROI
-> Do some operation on entire image
```

In this case how can I manage with c++ interface ?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the steps you need:

```
// Load image
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("image_filname");

// SetImageRoi
cv::Rect roi(x, y, width, height);
cv::Mat image_roi = image(roi);
// note: this assignment does not copy data
// image and image_roi now share data

// Do some processing on ROI region
process(image_roi);
// any changes to image_roi will also be in image

// Reset ROI  
//     -- nothing required

// Do some operation on entire image 
operations(image);
```