# Setting Region of interest hand

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on cursor control using hand gestures. I have segmented my hand using opencv backprojection combined with backgroundsubtractorMOG.  What I want to know is , How to set the ROI as a rectangle around my palm. Using this rectangle I want to calculate the average convexity defects, within the rectangle and use this to differentiate the  different hand gesture. Any Ideas, I am useing Opencv in C++.

Comment: If you want know how to use ROI using OpenCV C++ see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621983/how-opencv-c-interface-manage-roi

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to train a HoG classifier and do [detectMultiScale](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html?highlight=detectmultiscale#cascade-classification).. The result would be a *Rect* that would contain the hand.