# C++ OpenCV: Iterate through pixels in a Mat which is ROI of another Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have a very large Mat which is actually a ROI of another Mat (obtained by otherMat(cv::Rect(x,y,w,h))). I want to go through all the pixels of the Mat, do some pixelwise computation and write the result to another Mat by using a pointer.

Going through all pixels, including the ones outside the ROI is working fine so far, but I am wondering what the fastest way of skipping the pixels outside the ROI is. I want to have as few cache misses as possible and also I don't want to have an inefficient branch prediction. What would be the best way to go about this?

Edit: I am not interested in getting a submatrix for a specifitc region  of interest. I am interested in iterating through the pixel by pointer in an maximally efficient way without accessing data outside the submatrix' region.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621983/how-opencv-c-interface-manage-roi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How OpenCV C++ Interface Manage ROI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621983/how-opencv-c-interface-manage-roi)

Comment: you could copy this ROI to a new `Mat` so that it's continuous, I don't think there is other way to avoid cache and branch prediction misses - try it and measure which is faster

Comment: this does seem a lot like a premature/micro optimization though, did you profile your application and find a bottleneck there?

Comment: Surely this is a small optimization, but since I am working on mobile devices, many small improvements can make a big difference. Regardless, I am interested in a generally optimal solution, independent of how much the actual run time advantage will be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a submatrix:

```
cv::Mat largeMat
cv::Rect roi(yourROI);
cv::Mat submatrix = largeMat(roi);

// now iterate over all the pixels of submatrix
```

you will have cache misses at the end of each row

Here's the actual code example which shows, that the pixels outside of the submat are skipped (you'll get an additional cache miss at the end of each row but that should be all).

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("C:/StackOverflow/Input/Lenna.png");

    cv::Rect roi(128, 128, 256, 256);
    cv::Mat submat = input(roi);

    cv::MatIterator_<cv::Vec3b> it; // = src_it.begin<cv::Vec3b>();
    for (it = submat.begin<cv::Vec3b>(); it != submat.end<cv::Vec3b>(); ++it)
    {
        (*it)[0] = 0;
        (*it)[1] = 0;
    }

    cv::imshow("input", input);
    cv::imwrite("C:/StackOverflow/Output/submatIter.png", input);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

giving this result:

[image]

If you want it a little faster you can use row-Pointers: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html

Please mind, that in the link they compared debug mode runtime speed, that's why the random access is so slow. In release mode it should be as fast (or maybe faster) than the iterator verson.
But here's the row-Ptr version (which spares to compute the row-offset on each pixel access) which gives the same result and should be the fastest way (if openCV's LUT function can't be used for your task):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("C:/StackOverflow/Input/Lenna.png");

    cv::Rect roi(128, 128, 256, 256);
    cv::Mat submat = input(roi);

    cv::Vec3b * currentRow;

    for (int j = 0; j < submat.rows; ++j)
    {
        currentRow = submat.ptr<cv::Vec3b>(j);
        for (int i = 0; i < submat.cols; ++i)
        {
            currentRow[i][0] = 0;
            currentRow[i][1] = 0;
        }
    }

    cv::imshow("input", input);
    cv::imwrite("C:/StackOverflow/Output/submatIter.png", input);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was doing initially. The problem is, if I iterate through all pixels then I will also iterate through pixels outside of the submatrix..

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Using the iterators is a great idea and does what I was initially trying to do by using pointers to the data directly.

Comment: if you want to use pointer to `.data` directly, you can still do it, but you'll have to use `submat.step()` to be sure to work on the right values. For example use `submat.data[row*submat.step() + column*nChannels*valueDepth + currentChannel*valueDepth]` but that's essentially the same as using the row-pointers. Iterators are nice and simple, but might be a bit slower.

Answer (score 0):

As the OtherMat is a subset of Original mat and you want to do operation over the original mat but only inside the otherMat Region

```
//As otherMat(cv::Rect(x,y,w,h)));
for(int j=x;j<x+w;j++) 
{
  for (int i=y;i<y+h;i++)
  {  
       original.at<uchar>(j,i) = 255; 
  }
}
```

Comment: There are two things that I find problematic with the answer: 1. You step through the matrix as if it were column major, although it is row major. This will lead to a very large performance degradation. 2. You are using random access instead of pointers, which, again, does not yield a very good performance.

Comment: `.at<uchar>` will give very good performance (if row major was used) in release mode (in debug mode there are additional checks for matrix dimensions etc), just a minimal slower slower than the pointer version. Caching etc. would be nice (if row major would be used instead) with a single cache miss at the end of each row.