# Drawing "soft" circles with transparent edges with cv2/opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I need to draw "soft" white circles (translucent borders) onto an image with OpenCV, but all I can find in the docs is how to draw 100% opaque circles with hard borders. Does anyone know how I could do this, or at least create the illusion that the circles "fade out" at the edges?

Comment: There may be an easier way, but you could create a large square in a separate 4-channel (BGRA) Mat at the start of your program and fill it with white. Then make the alpha channel go from solid (opaque) in the middle to transparent at the edges in a radial fashion - using `hypot()` probably. When you want a soft circle, resize this and alpha-blend it onto your image http://jepsonsblog.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/overlay-transparent-image-in-opencv.html

Comment: Or draw a solid circle in said alpha channel and blur it.

Comment: Thanks! The solid circle in the alpha channel + blurring it seems like a pretty good strategy.

Comment: Mmm, I tried it and it's not very good - the first idea works better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I felt like working on my OpenCV skills a bit - and learned quite a lot - cool question!

I generated a single channel image of alpha values - float to get fewer rounding errors, and single channel to save some memory. This represents how much of your circle is visible over the background.

The circle has an outer radius - the point at which it becomes fully transparent and an inner radius, the point where it stops being fully opaque. Radii between these two will be faded. So, set the IRADIUS very close to the ORADIUS for a steep, rapid falloff and set it a long way away for a slower tapering out.

I used an ROI to position the circle on the background and to speed things up by only iterating over the necessary rectangle of the background.

The only tricky part is alpha blending or compositing. You just have to know the formula for each pixel in the output image is:

```
out = (alpha * foreground) + (1-alpha) * background
```

Here is the code. I am not the world's best at `OpenCV` so there may be parts that can be optimised!

---

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// main.cpp
// Mark Setchell
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#define ORADIUS 100 // Outer radius
#define IRADIUS  80 // Inner radius

int main()
{
   // Create a blue background image
   Mat3b background(400,600,Vec3b(255,0,0));

   // Create alpha layer for our circle normalised to 1=>solid, 0=>transparent 
   Mat alpha(2*ORADIUS,2*ORADIUS,CV_32FC1);

   // Now draw a circle in the alpha channel
   for(auto r=0;r<alpha.rows;r++){
      for(auto c=0;c<alpha.cols;c++){
         int x=ORADIUS-r;
         int y=ORADIUS-c;
         float radius=hypot((float)x,(float)y);
         auto& pixel = alpha.at<float>(r,c);
         if(radius>ORADIUS){ pixel=0.0; continue;}      // transparent
         if(radius<IRADIUS){ pixel=1.0; continue;}      // solid
         pixel=1-((radius-IRADIUS)/(ORADIUS-IRADIUS));  // partial
      }
   }

   // Create solid magenta rectangle for circle
   Mat3b circle(2*ORADIUS,2*ORADIUS,Vec3b(255,0,255));

#define XPOS 20
#define YPOS 120
   // Make an ROI on background where we are going to place circle
   Rect ROIRect(XPOS,YPOS,ORADIUS*2,ORADIUS*2);
   Mat  ROI(background,ROIRect);

   // Do the alpha blending thing
   Vec3b *thisBgRow;
   Vec3b *thisFgRow;
   float *thisAlphaRow;
   for(int j=0;j<ROI.rows;++j)
   {
       thisBgRow    = ROI.ptr<Vec3b>(j);
       thisFgRow    = circle.ptr<Vec3b>(j);
       thisAlphaRow = alpha.ptr<float>(j);
       for(int i=0;i<ROI.cols;++i)
       {
          for(int c=0;c<3;c++){   // iterate over channels, result=circle*alpha + (1-alpha)*background
             thisBgRow[i][c] = saturate_cast<uchar>((thisFgRow[i][c]*thisAlphaRow[i]) + ((1.0-thisAlphaRow[i])*thisBgRow[i][c]));
          }
       }
   }

   imwrite("result.png",background);
   return 0;
}
```

This is with `IRADIUS=80`:

[image]

This is with `IRADIUS=30`:

[image]

Kudos and thanks to @Micka for sharing his code for iterating over a ROI [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42803771/2836621).

Oooops, I just realised you were looking for a Python solution. Hopefully my code will give you some ideas for generating the soft circle mask, and I found an article [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/alpha-blending-using-opencv-cpp-python/) that shows you some Python-style ways of doing it that you can mash up with my code.

Comment: thanks so much! And yeah, even though I was asking for a python solution your code definitely helps (And is probably the most helpful answer i've gotten on this website :p)

Comment: Excellent! Good luck with your project.